# Mishnayos per Perek and or masechta

Tags: mishna

Can someone tell me how many mishnayos are there per Perek and how many perakim per masechata, as well as total mishnayos per Seder and perek per seder?

Comment: Perskim per masechta is covered [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88014/is-the-number-of-chapters-per-tractate-relevant)

Comment: Thanks Alex but that really isn’t clear enough